# CSS or Javascript: Custom popup

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make custom popup, for example, as Quora does when clicking a button:

[image]

How can I do this ? I don't know do this by using CSS or javascript, so I put question's title as above.

Thanks :)

Comment: This is not a "give me the code" kind of service.

Comment: Protip: read the Quora source code.

Comment: if you dont have any code to show, then a few seconds on google will point you in the right direction

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: @MatteoTassinari I can tell you there are many questions on here StackOverFlow "give me the code" as you see ;) just because I don't have direction in here. If you see this problem is easy, welcome. But I don't. There are many questions on StackOverFlow seems easy too. I have searched and don't see suitable result :)

Comment: @j08691 no. I don't want to use any frameworks here :)

Comment: Yes, and all of those questions are in the wrong place. Most of them are voted down and closed.

Comment: @TrầnKimDự google is your friend :) just google "Javascript Custom popup"

Comment: No frameworks? Then feel free to reinvent the wheel!

Comment: @atornblad I can give you many questions as you can. don't voted down. dont close. And about "reinvente the wheel", so funny :) put a large library to do something that I think not big :)

Comment: @atornblad he does have a point, IMO there is really no need to use a library for somthing this simple

Comment: ...and then the web site grows. Someone wants to add a login dialog, and there is no need for a library to add a simple login dialog. Then someone wants to add a picture carousel, and there is no need for a library for a simple thing like that. Then someone wants to add...

Comment: @TrầnKimDự instead of wasting time replying to comments, why don't you give it a shot in solving the issue? If you do not wish to use JQuery, you can still achieve the popup with an absolute positioned `div` with higher `z-index` and the background having a lower `opacity`. The amount of customization you need to make is considerably higher compared to if you use a plugin like JQuery!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've no code I can't suggest changes to what you've got. googling your problem will find you hundreds of code examples.

As a high level answer, you'd need:

1. html mark up for your pop up, hidden with css
2. some sort of trigger to fire a javascript function to do something to change the hidden state of the pop up mark up (like removing a `hidden` class)

Another option would be:

1. a trigger that when fired injects the required html mark up into the page and then destroys the mark up on completion of what ever purpose it has. (beware of memory issues when tearing down though)

Answer (score -2):

This is the line of code you use in Javascript to open a new window. The new window can have it's own css, so it's customizable.

```
window.open("./mypages/mypage.html", "_blank", "toolbar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=50, left=500, width=740, height=900");
```

The new page is mypage.html.
It is in top:50 and left:500.
It's height is 900px and it's width is 740px.